# Manually add the latest Dotnetzip version to c# asp.net web forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, webforms

Hi I am new to c# and  I am failing to manually add Dotnetzip to my project

I can not use nuget Package manager to install Dotnetzip for compressing and zipping my files  because I don't have access to internet on the machine I am using to write the code in but would still like to get the library to work.

I  downloaded the library zip folder from https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd.git   and extracted the files but failed to reference the library to the project because I could not locate the Ionic.Zip.dll file.

The .NET  inbuilt  Deflate Stream and GzipStream do not give me the compression ratios I want as I would like to significantly compress the file before sending it via email.

I will appreciate any support on this.

Thank you

Comment: You may be able to add a NuGet package even when offline: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/01/02/adding-nuget-packages-when-offline

Comment: If you download the source code then of course there's no compiled assembly. You have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thank you both @MarkSeemann  and JIm.  I opted to use ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.  My other question is what solution can I implement to  optimally compress a 12mb file to 5mb before zipping and sending it as an attachment via email.

Comment: If you have another question, then please ask a new question, i.e. a new post.